# How to generate junit tests given an XSD

Tags: java, unit-testing, xsd, jaxb, schema

Currently our XSD schema changes quite a bit and we want to it to create junit tests that will break whenever an existing data type gets re-defined.

For example, if there was a field `"YearBuilt"` defined as a `"Integer"` originally and someone comes along and changes this to be a `"String"`, we want this `jUnit` test to fail.

Is there any utilities or programs which will take in an existing schema and generate the appropriate unit tests for all the datatypes? We currently generate `jaxb` objects. Is there some program which can generate `junits` for a set of `jaxb` objects?

Comment: Curious.  May I ask what types of changes *are* allowed to your XSDs?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these changes - changes like the Integer to String **are allowed**. But we want to make sure that these changes are deliberately done and that the developer changes both the schema AND the unit tests (as you would normally when changing code logic).